# 404 Not Found after installing fresh Magento 2.4.2

Tags: installation, magento2.4.2, 404-page

I installed Magento 2.4.2 successfully, but after installation home page gives error: 404 not found. Please suggest a solution for this.

I have used PHP -7.4 Mysql - 8.0 Nginx 1.18.0

****The following is the error****

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Check this : https://www.rohanhapani.com/solved-404-not-found-after-fresh-magento-2-4-2-installation/

Comment: @RohanHapani I am looking for Nginx however your solution for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is due to the change brought in 2.4.2 where the website pages are now served from the `/pub` folder. So you need to update your configurations to point to that location.

1. Check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html and follow all steps presented there (magento base urls, webserver settings, env.file, etc).
2. For nginx, just follow the https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html#a-note-about-nginx guide, your document root should be set to `<magento_proj_folder>/pub`. This should do it :)

good luck!

Comment: I tried as per above document however,  I am getting the same 404 not found.